# Can't resize Canvas size using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8.1

Very simple issue: if I declare a canvas in XAML in a Windows Phone 8.1 app like so:

```
<Canvas x:Name="OptionsCanvas" Width="400" Height="450"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" PointerMoved="OptionsCanvas_PointerMoved">
```

It works fine, but I want to make my app adjust to phones with different screen sizes. So I'm getting the screen size using `Window.Current.Bounds` and setting the canvas dimensions as a ratio of the total screen size in c# in the page's constructor like so:

```
Point screenRes = new Point();
double scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
ScreenRes.X = Window.Current.Bounds.Width * scaleFactor;
ScreenRes.Y = Window.Current.Bounds.Height * scaleFactor;
MyCanvas.Width = ScreenRes.X * 0.5;
MyCanvas.Height = ScreenRes.Y * 0.7;
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. When I check the `MyCanvas.ActualHeight` and `MyCanvas.ActualWidth` properties after running the above code, both dimensions are zero and consequently, nothing shows in my canvas.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to check what values you're assigning to `MyCanvas.Width` and `MyCanvas.Height`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried assigning constant values to `MyCanvas.Width` and `MyCanvas.Height` and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know that `Canvas` doesn't clip its children. So even if its size is 0 x 0 all controls that are inside will be visible. I suggest you to use some different control to show the background that is more flexible, like `Border` and leave canvas as it is (with default 0 x 0 size). So your code could look like this:

```
<Border x:Name="OptionsBorder" 
        Width="400" 
        Height="450"  
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Background="White" 
        PointerMoved="OptionsCanvas_PointerMoved">
    <Canvas x:Name="OptionsCanvas"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Border>
```

So now you can change the size of `OptionsBorder` instead and don't care about canvas. Canvas has only one advantage - you can arrange your controls using `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` like X and Y.